# How to avoid truncated bubbles when elasticX or elasticY

Tags: d3.js, dc.js

When you have an elastic chart and bubbles that are close to an axis (or close to the borders of the graph), the bubbles are truncated

https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/issues/998#issuecomment-216927317

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add extra padding (xAxisPadding and yAxisPadding), but as the padding are on both sides of the graph, you end up loosing a lot of space and having the bubbles packed in the middle.

On workaround is to draw outside of the graph, so the bubbles are visible under the axis. To do that, remove the clipping:

```
  dc.bubbleChart('#bubbly') 
  .on('renderlet', function(chart, filter){
    chart.svg().select(".chart-body").attr("clip-path",null);
  })
  ...
```