# Avoid bubbles from hiding/cutting in dc charts

Tags: javascript, data-visualization, dc.js

I've a bubble chart built using [dc.js](http://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/) in which the bubbles are getting hidden. Is there a property to avoid this behaviour?

[image: bubbles getting hidden]

Here is the code:

```js
payerBubbleChart = dc.bubbleChart('#payer-chart');

payerBubbleChart
  .width(450).height(chartHeight).transitionDuration(1500).margins({
    top: 20,
    right: 50,
    bottom: 30,
    left: 40
  })
  .dimension(payerDim)
  .group(payerGroup)
  .colors(colorbrewer.RdYlBu[9])
  .colorDomain([0, 100])
  .colorAccessor(function(d) {
    return (d.value.denialCount / d.value.claimCount);
  })
  .keyAccessor(function(p) {
    return p.value.denialCount;
  })
  .valueAccessor(function(p) {
    return p.value.revenue;
  })
  .radiusValueAccessor(function(d) {
    return (d.value.claimCount / 100);
  })
  .maxBubbleRelativeSize(0.3).x(d3.scale.linear()).y(d3.scale.linear())
  .r(d3.scale.linear().domain([0, 100]))
  .elasticY(true).elasticX(true)
  .yAxisPadding(100).xAxisPadding(100)
  .renderHorizontalGridLines(true).renderVerticalGridLines(true)
  .xAxisLabel('Denial Amount').yAxisLabel('Revenue')
  .renderLabel(true).label(function(p) {
    return p.key;
  })
  .renderTitle(true)
  .title(function(p) {

    return ['NDC: ' + p.key,
        'Revenue: $' + formatNumber(p.value.revenue, 1000, "k"),
        'Claims: ' + formatNumber(p.value.claimCount, 1000, "k"),
        'Denials: $' + formatNumber(p.value.denialCount, 1000, "k")
      ]
      .join('\n');
  })
  .yAxis().tickFormat(function(v) {
    return "$" + formatNumber(v, 1000, "k");
  });
payerBubbleChart
  .xAxis().tickFormat(function(v) {
    return "$" + formatNumber(v, 1000, "k");
  });
payerBubbleChart.xAxisMin = function() {
  return 0;
};
payerBubbleChart.yAxisMin = function() {
  return 0;
};
```

I applied `d3.scale.log` for `.x` or `.r`? and chart disappears.

[image: dc chart disappears]

Comment: Maybe changing your axis scale from linear to logarithmic (`d3.scale.log`) would help?

Comment: @Marek The chart is disappearing now. Any advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are at least two ways to deal with this. One is to use `xAxisPadding` and `yAxisPadding` to bring the chart outside the bubble.

These are in domain units, so 100 is pretty small for your values, which are in the thousands. Also you are deliberately stopping at 0 with that `yAxisMin`, `yAxisMax` trick.

Another way to deal with this is to simply remove the clipping, so that the bubbles are drawn partly outside the chart, as shown by @tttp in a related issue:

```
  dc.bubbleChart('#bubbly') 
  .on('renderlet', function(chart, filter){
    chart.svg().select(".chart-body").attr("clip-path",null);
  })
```

https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/issues/998#issuecomment-216558123

Also, this Q&A is sort of an expansion of [How to avoid truncated bubbles when elasticX or elasticY](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37042901/how-to-avoid-truncated-bubbles-when-elasticx-or-elasticy/37042902#37042902).